# React with TypeScript - LocalStorage won't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, local-storage, react-typescript

I am working with persistence on a todo application written with React and TypeScript.
I am using localStorage to get the persistence I want.

Let me show you some code.

```
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState<todoModel[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("todoItem", JSON.stringify(todos));
  }, [todos])

  const storesTodos = () => {
    const storedValues = localStorage.getItem("todoItem");
    if(!storedValues) { return todos; }

    return JSON.parse(storedValues);
  }

  useEffect(() => { getToDoList(); storesTodos(); 
  console.log("default") }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    if (!props.reload) return;
    console.log(props.reload)
    getToDoList();
    storesTodos();
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [props.reload])
```

I am adding the `StoresTodo()` function into my useEffects, I tried both of them.
But it won't work. I get the data into my localStorage, but when reloading the page, it gets back to default values.

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is `getToDoList`?  Why doesn't anything ever use the returned value from `storesTodos`?  It's not really clear to me what the expecation is with this code.  A default empty array is created for a state value, that state value is *never updated*, and you're writing that empty array to `localStorage` and reading it from `localStorage`, but doing nothing with the value that was read.

Comment: When the component loads initially, line 1 (useState call) will be set to empty array. You're not calling setTodos to update the array anywhere because of which the functionality doesn't work I think.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are getting the same initial value because you never update the `todos`, judging based on shared code.

You can do this

```
...

const storesTodos = () => {
  const storedValues = localStorage.getItem("todoItem");
  if(!storedValues) { 
    setTodos(todos)
    return todos; 
  }

    return JSON.parse(storedValues);
  }
```

Or you can use a local storage state hook from [here](https://kentcdodds.com/blog/javascript-to-know-for-react)

```
function useLocalStorageState({
  key,
  initialValue,
  serialize = v => v,
  deserialize = v => v,
}) {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(
    () => deserialize(window.localStorage.getItem(key)) || initialValue,
  )

  const serializedState = serialize(state)
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem(key, serializedState)
  }, [key, serializedState])

  return [state, setState]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh the page, even before the useEffect sets in

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<todoModel[]>([]);
```

already will set your initial todos array to an empty array.

Perhaps you'll need to perform the check on localStorage on it like so

```
const [todos, setTodos] = useState<todoModel[]>(() => {
   const storedValues = localStorage.getItem("todoItem"); 
   return storedValues ? JSON.parse(storedValues) : [];
});
```